# Issues when calling functions through IF Statement

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, menu, arduino

I'm finishing a project for a customer. Basically it's a interactive menu where he can send AT commands for a bluetooth module in a easier way.

The code is working at the first function ("padrao"). It sends the AT command properly. (also, ignore the missing part of the code)

The problem is: 
The only function able to be called by IF statement is "padrao". Any other function wont work. What can i change to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Tried to use SWITCH and CASE instead, but couldn't call any function like this...

(i left only one of the remaining functions for comparison. tell me if any of you guys need the rest of the code)

```
/* Menu interativo para comandos dos módulos Bluetooth HC-05, HC-06, HC-08, HM-10, etc.
 *  Nathan - 29/04/2019
 *  

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define rx 3
#define tx 4

SoftwareSerial Seria1(rx, tx); // Declara os pinos utilizados para a comunicação serial
int entrada = 0 ;
int echo;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Inicia a comunicação serial a 9600 bauds
  Seria1.begin(9600); // Inicia a interface serial de software a 9600 bauds
  Serial.println("Interface de testes Bluetooth ver. 0.1");
  Serial.println("Escolha uma opção pelo terminal serial");
  Serial.println("1. Redefinir o módulo para as configurações de fábrica");
  Serial.println("2. Reset");
  Serial.println("3. Verificar o endereço do módulo");
  Serial.println("4. Verificar o nome do módulo [como será reconhecido]");
  Serial.println("5. Mudar o nome do módulo");

  //Teste da variável "entrada". Debug apenas.
  //Serial.println(entrada);

  pinMode (LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop () {
if (Serial.available()){
    entrada = Serial.parseInt();
    delay(100);

  if (entrada == 1) 
  { 
    echo == entrada;
    padrao();

    }
    if (entrada == 2) {
      Seria1.write("AT+RST");
      entrada = 0;
    }
    if (entrada == 3) {
      Seria1.write("AT+ADDR?");
      entrada = 0;
    if (entrada == 9) {

      nome();

      }
    if (entrada == 4) {
        char comando[] = "AT+NAME=";
        Serial.println ("Digite o nome do dispositivo desejado");
        while(!Serial.available() ){
        }
          int nome = Serial.read();
          Seria1.write (comando + nome);
          entrada = 0;
        }
      }
      if (entrada == 5) {
        Seria1.write ("AT+ROLE=0");
        entrada = 0;
        }
       if (entrada == 6) {
        Seria1.write ("AT+ROLE=1");
        entrada = 0;
      }
        if (entrada == 7) {
        Seria1.write ("AT+PSWD?");
        entrada = 0;
        }
        if (entrada == 8) {
        Seria1.write ("AT+STATE?");
        entrada = 0;
        }
    }
}

void padrao() {

    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,LOW); 
    Serial.println("Deseja resetar o dispositivo para as configurações padrão?");
    Serial.println("Digite '1' para prosseguir");
    int resposta = Serial.parseInt();
    while (resposta != 1) {
      if (resposta == 1) {
        break;
      }
      }
    {
      delay(1000);
      Seria1.write("AT+ORGL");
      Serial.print("Comando enviado!");
      entrada = 0;
    }
}
void nome() {
        delay(100);
        Serial.write("O nome do dispositivo é:");
        Seria1.write("AT+NAME?");
        //debug
        Serial.print("teste");
        entrada = 0;
}
```

Comment: That opening block comment should end in `*/` shouldn't it? The syntax highlighting is all off. I'd fix it, but I don't want to risk that somehow being the cause of the error (although I don't think it could possibly be).

Comment: Also are you missing a brace for `if (entrada == 3) {`, because afterwards you reset `entrada = 0` then check if it's 9...

Comment: Please expand upon "won't work" -- does it not compile? Does it give a run-time error? Does it make your computer explode? Some other malfunction?

Comment: What's up with the indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
    if (entrada == 3) {
      Seria1.write("AT+ADDR?");
      entrada = 0;
    if (entrada == 9) {

      nome();

      }
    if (entrada == 4) {
```

Basically if entrada == 3, then you enter this block where you potentially call nome().

However, if entrada == 3, it can not possibly be equal to nine. Further, you reset entrada to 0 just before testing if it is 9. So there is no way entrada can be 9 and thus no way for nome to be called.

Probably you intended for the code to read like this:

```
    if (entrada == 3) {
      Seria1.write("AT+ADDR?");
      entrada = 0;
    }                // The previous if statement was not ended.
    if (entrada == 9) {

      nome();

    }
    if (entrada == 4) {
```

You will need to remove a closing brace from further down in the code.

Also, I noted that you have this:

```
    if (entrada == 4) {
        char comando[] = "AT+NAME=";
        Serial.println ("Digite o nome do dispositivo desejado");
        while(!Serial.available() ){
        }
          int nome = Serial.read();             // See below
          Seria1.write (comando + nome);
          entrada = 0;
        }
      }
```

Usually it is not a good idea to use the same name for a variable and other purposes (i.e. the nome() function). In this case it is probably OK, but it could get confusing later - especially if this block of code got larger and you needed to call the nome() function from within it.

Lastly, the echo == line of code does not do anything. Is that what you intended?

```
  if (entrada == 1) 
  { 
    echo == entrada;      // This is a non-operation. Did you mean for it to be something else?
    padrao();

    }
```

I hope this helps with your project. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'll fix it and share the results!

Comment: Abou the echo, i was supposed to comment it. I used it for debugging and forgot to erase it from the example code. My mistake

Comment: And... yeah, i forgot to end that "if (entrada == 3)" statement ... thanks lol

Comment: No problem - hopefully this has helped you call the other function. If so, can you please accept the answer? Thanks